# How would I go about creating a keras model with a varying number of targets/outputs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I've set up a neural network regression model using Keras with one target. This works fine,
now I'd like to include multiple targets. The dataset includes a total of 30 targets, and I'd rather train one neural network instead of 30 different ones.

My problem is that in the preprocessing of the data I have to remove some target values, for a given example, as they represent unphysical values that are not to be predicted.
This creates the issues that I have a varying number of targets/output.
For example:
Targets =

1. None, 0.007798, 0.012522
2. 0.261140, 2110.000000, 2440.000000
3. 0.048799, None, None

How would I go about creating a keras.Sequential model(or functional) with a varying number of outputs for a given input?

<s>edit: Could I perhaps first train a classification model that predicts the number of outputs given some test inputs, and then vary the number of outputs in the output layer according to this prediction? I guess I would have to use the functional API for something like that.</s>

The "classification" edit here is unnecessary, i.e. ignore it. The number of outputs of the test targets is a known quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment)
First, do you know up front whether some of the output values will be invalid or is part of the problem predicting which outputs will actually be valid?

If you don't know up front which outputs to disregard, you could go with something like the 2-step approach you described in your comment.

If it is deterministic (and you know how so) which outputs will be valid for any given input and your problem is just how to set up a proper model, here's how I would do that in keras:

- Use the functional API
- Create 30 named output layers (e.g. out_0, out_1, ... out_29)

  - When creating the model, just use the outputs argument to list all 30 outputs
- When compiling the model, specify a loss for each separate output, you can do this by passing a dictionary to the loss argument where the keys are the names of your output layers and the values are the respective losses

  - Assuming you'll use mean-squared error for all outputs, the dictionary will look something like {'out_0': 'mse', 'out_1': 'mse', ..., 'out_29': 'mse'}
- When passing inputs to the models, pass three things per input: x, y, loss-weights

  - y has to be a dictionary where the key is the output layer name and the value is the target output value
  - The loss-weights are also a dictionary in the same format as y. The weights in your case can just be binary, 1 for each output that corresponds to a real value, 0 for each output that corresponds to unphysical values (so they are disregarded during training) for any given sample
  - Don't pass None's for the unphysical value targets, use some kind of numeric filler, otherwise you'll get issues. It is completely irrelevant what you use for your filler as it will not affect gradients during training

This will give you a trainable model. BUT once you move on from training and try to predict on new data, YOU will have to decide which outputs to disregard for each sample, the network will likely still give you "valid"-looking outputs for those inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer. Yes I realized that I do know up front. So sorry for the edit I had about classification, turns out it wasn't relevant.
I will try out your step by step solution and get back to you with the result. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to have a separate output of "validity flags" which takes values in range from zero to one. For example, your first target will be

```
y=[0.0, 0.007798, 0.012522]
yf=[0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

where zeros indicate invalid values.
Use sigmoid activation function for `yf`.
Loss function can be the sum of losses for `y` and `yf`.
During inference, analyze the network output for `yf` and only consider `y` value valid if corresponding `yf` exceeds 0.5 threshold